# python, using recording.js convert blob to wav file

Tags: javascript, python, audio-recording

I am trying to record the audio from the web using recording.js, then send the blob data to python to save it as wav file in my server directory. Now it is creating wav file in my server, but it does not have proper sound which i record. I don't know which part is wrong.

JavaScript Front end

```
rec.exportWAV(upload);

function upload(blob) {
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload=function(e) {
      if(this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
      }
  };
  var filename = new Date().toISOString();
  var fd=new FormData();
  fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
  console.log(blob);
  xhr.open("POST","/testFlask/saveAudio",true);
  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Python

```
@app.route("/saveAudio", methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello2():
    if request.method =='POST':
        #form = cgi.FieldStorage()
        fname = request.files['audio_data'].filename
        blob = request.files['audio_data']
        #blob = open("/home/ubuntu/abc/testing.wav").read()
        name = "output.wav"
        #f = open("/home/ubuntu/pabc/audio/text.txt", 'wb')
        #f.close()
        audio = wave.open('/home/ubuntu/abc/audio/'+fname+'.wav', 'wb')

        audio.setnchannels(1)
        audio.setsampwidth(1)
        audio.setframerate(8000)
        audio.setnframes(1)
        audio.writeframes(blob.read())
        audio.close()
        return blob.read()
```